# word image watermark automation

Tags: visual-foxpro, word-automation

working with word 2010, I need to place image watermark on all pages. I recorded macro and want to know the exact

```
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.Select
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:="image.jpg", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Name = "WordPictureWatermark11907540"
 Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Brightness = 0.85
Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Contrast = 0.15
    Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = True
Selection.ShapeRange.Height = CentimetersToPoints(20.32)
Selection.ShapeRange.Width = CentimetersToPoints(27.09)
Selection.ShapeRange.WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = True
Selection.ShapeRange.WrapFormat.Side = wdWrapNone
Selection.ShapeRange.WrapFormat.Type = 3
Selection.ShapeRange.RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
Selection.ShapeRange.RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
Selection.ShapeRange.Left = wdShapeCenter
Selection.ShapeRange.Top = wdShapeCenter
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
```

Comment: I don't recommend trying to translate the macro line by line. Instead, use what it tells you to figure out what objects you need to work with. In this case, it's telling you to add a picture to the Shapes collection of the HeaderFooter object and then to set properties of that shape. I'd do this by working from the Command Window, trying different variations until I got what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with Tamar's comments to a degree, what I have found very useful and how Microsoft does things is via Macro Recorder.

Sometimes trying to guess at what they do behind the scenes is troubling.  Go into Word, do a sample of what you want to figure out HOW to do it.  Then, Start with a brand new Word document, turn on Macro Recorder and start recording and do the steps to get your watermark in place.  Then stop the recorder.  You can then review the recorded macro and it will be in Visual Basic, but it will provide a bunch of things that might help including object references, properties.  Hope this helps and also works with other M$ products (Word, Excel, Outlook, etc)

EDIT---

To gain access to other features not within the normal ribbon that would otherwise need double-click, right-click, etc, you can customize the Ribbon.  While in Word (or Excel), right-click an open area within the ribbon and click "Customize the Ribbon".  This will bring up a dialog of the most popular commands by default in a left-side selection list.  In the right side are the common ribbon main tabs like: Home, Insert, Page Layout, etc.  You can add a new tab for your testing purposes, then start adding the commands you need to the ribbon tab to run with, such as headers, tables, etc.  Above the left-side selection area is a combobox for "Choose commands from" (Default is Popular Commands).  Change this to "All Commands" and you'll get way more than you expect... Then, add the ones you need to your custom tab for the ribbon, save and exit back to your document.  Now, start your macro recorder and you'll have all those commands that you would not otherwise have via double-click, right-click, etc.

Comment: on some steps like working with tables, headers and mini-menu, when recording macro, the right mouse button cannot be used, any suggestion ?

Comment: @user3876120, updated answer for working with recorder and getting other commands not typically available by default.